# Laravel Connect Posts and Categories

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have three tables

```
Posts with ID
Post_Categories with ID, Post_ID and Category_id
Categories with ID
```

And I need to get all categories for one specific post can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code to the Posts Model

```
 public function categories()
 {
     return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'categories_posts','Category_ID','Post_ID') ;
 }
```

and then to pull out all categories of one post you just have to do like this

```
$myPost = Post::find(idPost); 
$myPost->categories ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is classic many-to-many relation, in `Laravel` it is done like this:

```
class Post
{

    function categories()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'Post_Categories');
    }

}
```